# How to merge eyelash into face mesh and shape key?

Tags: mesh, shape-keys

I made face shape keys, then I copied a new separate eyelash from someone else. It is made from a curve. I want to merge the eyelash into the face shape key, how? As the shape key must be for one mesh, so I tried to join the eyelash into the face mesh. But it says can not join mesh with a curve.

Comment: So I guess to either shapekey the eyelash as a different object or convert it to mesh and then join it to the face

Answer (score 1):

Select your eyelash curve object in the 3d viewport in OBJECT MODE.
Go to to the top menu in the 3d viewport > Object>convert>mesh.
In the outliner you can see the curve object icon changed to a "mesh" icon.
You can now merge the eyelash, but since it doesn't have any blend shape it will mess up your base mesh blink shape from the face. It will not do anything.
Go to edit mode and adjust the eyelash mesh according to the blend shape at 1 and at 0.
[image: Object>convert>mesh]